# Как сделать из /?id=123 это /id/123/

Tags: php, windows-server-2012

Как можно сделать чтобы при заходе на страницу https://example/test/?id=123 это https://example/test/id/123/ и при этом не создавая папок.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в зависимости от версии вашего windows-server, документацию, связанную с mod_rewrite. Все что вам нужно - это правильно задать правила маршрутизации в web.config файле.

Comment: Это я понимаю, но конкретно какие?

Answer (score -1):

Для того чтобы сделать это нужно изменять конфигурацию .hetaccess который есть у каждого сайта. Вот [полное руководство для изменения этого файла](http://astra.red/rukovodstvo-po-htaccess-tryuki-i-priemyi/)

Но на windows server это web.config

Comment: Человек использует windows server, на windows server нет .htaccess файла

Comment: Не заметил тег)

Comment: Ничего страшного), бывает.

Comment: @Mully "на windows server нет .htaccess файла". Это кто вам такое сказал?Файл `.htaccess` - это файл относящийся к программе Apache, а не к операционной системе. Apache, работающий на windows, отлично пользуется .htaccess.

Comment: Вы все верно сказали. Но в данном случае, ориентируясь на метку: "windows-server-2012", которая говорит о том что в качестве веб сервера человек использует предположительно ASP application, и конфиг в нем называется `web.config` а не `.htaccess`

Comment: @Mully только это называется не "ASP application", а IIS

Comment: Прошу прощения, я хотел передать суть, что в проблеме не используется Apache